# Change user using gotty cli

Tags: terminal

I created a user on my os(linux). I want to start the gotty with that user. But couldn't done it.

gotty -w -p (port) "su - username" didnt work. (Actually work but runned and close the connection)

I can only interact with gotty actively with this command: gotty -w -p (port) bash.

How can i change user with gotty and go on like bash on browser with using gotty cli?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tihs core linux command run commands for a specific user

```
runuser -l $1 -c "gotty -w -once -p 3000
```